# iPhone charges when using tethered internet (usb)

Tags: usb-power

I'm using my iPhone to provide tethered internet to my Pi.
However I see my iPhone is actually charging while connected. Would anyone considered this bad for the Pi? I never figured there would be enough juice to charge the phone off the Pi's USB.

I could always go the way of WiFi connect to the phone if that is safer.

Comment: If I plug my phone in it draws too much power from the Pi for it to connect properly. However, if it works then it should not damage it.

Answer (score 2):

The iPhone is not charged by Pi, it's charged by your power supply. If your power supply could provide enough juice, you'll be fine. If you want to be extra careful, check the voltage between TP1 and TP2 when iPhone is connected and disconnected, there should be no big difference.

Comment: Agreed. If its the new Rev C models without polyfuses and he is using a 1A or higher charger then the iphone will charge pretty happily. Just to add. No damage will occur if the `juice` runs out- He will notice the Pi resetting - To fix that get a bigger charger. Like a 2A power supply!